# Call to action at the end of a URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, button, action

I have a URL that leads to an Amazon reporting page. The URL looks like this (shortened for clarity):
https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/dateUnit=1&viewDateUnits=ALL&runDate=

In the page, there is a button to download the report as a CSV file. Is there a way to call the button action by adding the button ID at the end of the URL?
IF this is possible, it may look like this:
https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/gp/dateUnit=1&viewDateUnits=ALL&runDate=&export.downloadCSV

This is the code behind the button:

```
<div id="actionsBar" style="display: block;">
        <div class="actionsButton actionsDD" id="export">
            <span class="actionsLabel">Download</span>
            <ul class="actionsDDsub" style="display: none;">
                <li><span id="downloadCSV">CSV</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="actionsArrow"></div>
        </div>
           <div class="actionsButton actionsDD" id="pivot" style="display: none;">
            <span class="actionsLabel">Pivot</span>
            <ul class="actionsDDsub" style="display: none;">
                <li><span id="pivotButton">SKU Performance</span></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="actionsArrow"></div>
        </div>
          <div id="backToDate" class="actionsButton actionsBTN" style="display:none">
            <span class="actionsLabel">Return to Date Report</span>
            <div class="actionsNoArrow"></div>
        </div>
            <div id="sortedBy"></div>
    </div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: try to write those csv data on file and download that file rather than call to action. if they change the id or whatever you used to trigger click action then you need to change your code as well.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. So I need to find the direct path to the CSV file? The problem is that it is created dynamically after selecting various options and filters. Also after clicking on the Download button, the URL stays the same, so I don't have a clue for the actual CSV file path. Is there a tool for recording everything that happens behind the scenes when I click the download button or a way to determine if this information comes from a database or a JSON file etc?

Comment: I don't know about that. but I guess there isn't any tool for recording.